# How to add Ojdbc jar in classpath Spring Boot Jar?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on Spring boot application. I run my application via a batch file using:

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.additional-location=file:/config/ -Dspring.profiles.active=profile myApplication.jar
pause
```

This is working fine. However, I want to delete `Ojdbc6` jar entry from my Pom file and define it to my classpath via a batch file, like so:

```
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%ojdbc6.jar;
echo %CLASSPATH%
java -jar -Dspring.config.additional-location=file:/config/ -Dspring.profiles.active=profile myApplication.jar --classpath=%CLASSPATH%
pause
```

This is not working and I'm getting an error:

```
Unable to create initial connections of pool. 
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver from ClassLoader:org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@439f5b3d;ClassLoader:TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader

  context: application name

  delegate: true

----------> Parent Classloader:

org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@439f5b3d

    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:292)**
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-classpath=%CLASSPATH%` instead of `--classpath=%CLASSPATH%`

Ref. link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply I also checked with this but issue still there.. same error come